# check for 'null' timestamp values

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema, nullif

I wanted to check if a field has a "null" value. If so, I wanted to replace the "null" with a NULL value. This works for normal fields:

```
 SELECT NULLIF(JSON_DATA:"TO_Creator"::string, 'null') as "TO_CREATOR" FROM TABLE
```

However, it doesn't work with timestamps :

```
NULLIF(JSON_DATA:"TO_Collected_Date_Time"::timestamp_ntz, 'null') as "TO_COLLECTED_DATE_TIME",
```

This would later throw errors that:

```
SQL Error [100035] [22007]: Timestamp 'null' is not recognized
```

How can I check the same thing for NULL values within the timestamp field too?

Comment: NULLIF takes two arguments that must be the same type. The string literal 'null' is not the same type as the first argument (timestamp_ntz). Your first example works because both arguments are the same type (string).

Answer (score 1):

In this scenario [TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/functions/try_to_timestamp.html) should suffice:

> A special version of TO_TIMESTAMP / TO_TIMESTAMP_* that performs the same operation (i.e. converts an input expression into a timestamp), **but with error-handling support (i.e. if the conversion cannot be performed, it returns a NULL value instead of raising an error)**

```
SELECT TRY_TO_TIMESTAMP_NTZ(JSON_DATA:"TO_Collected_Date_Time"::STRING)
```

Comment: still gives the same error actually